# Evalute an Xpath attribute using XPathFactory

Tags: java, xml, xpath, rest-assured

I'm trying to do something quite simple I think, simply assert that an attribute of an Xpath node is a specific value. The node has no value, onlya an attribute value as follows:-
`<ControlResponse Success="true"/>` (will return "true" or "false")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tag0:AAA_ControlRS xmlns:tag0="http://www.xmltravel.com/fab/2002/09" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Target="test"     Version="2002A" xsi:type="AAA_ControlRS">
<tag0:TestInfo TestId="THFTEST"/>
<tag0:SessionInfo CreateNewSession="true"/>
<AAASessionId="8IzujBAVOPVQrO1ySpNBoJ9x"/>
<tag0:ControlResponse Success="true"/>
</tag0:AAA_ControlRS>
```

and here is my code:

```
//REQUEST
    String controlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n...
//bunch of xml here";

   //RESPONSE
    String myControlResponse = given().
            when().
            request().
            contentType("text/xml").
            body(myControlRequest).
            when().post().andReturn().asString();

    //Parse response and get relevant node via Xpath
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    Document doc;

    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse(new InputSource((new StringReader(myControlResponse))));

        //Xpath Factory Object
        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

        //Xpath Object
        XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

        String controlResponse = getNodeValue(doc, xpath);

        assertEquals("true", controlResponse);


    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | org.xml.sax.SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getNodeValue(Document doc, XPath xpath) {
    String controlResponse = null;
    try {
        XPathExpression expr =
                xpath.compile("//ControlResponse/@Success");
        controlResponse = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return controlResponse;
}
```

The xpath evaluates to null when I expect the String "true". I want to achieve getting the *attribute value* and asserting if it contains string "true" or "false"

Is there an easier way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

To get the *attribute value*, use `//ControlResponse/@Success` as the XPath expression.

If namespace issues get in your way, use `//*[local-name()="ControlResponse"]/@Success` for a quick check, if the problem is namespace related.

Example using an unrelated sample document:

```
> cat ~/test.xml
<root><foo bar="true"/></root>
> xmllint --xpath '//foo/@bar' ~/test.xml
 bar="true"
```

If this doesn't work as expected in your case, please show enough of the XML document that the problem is reproducible.

Comment: thanks, I updated the code but that XPath expression evalutes to null?

Comment: @Steerpike updated the answer... possible your input XML has namespaces?

Comment: thank you. I am unsure about Namespaces but I just googled and I think you're correct.  I have posted the full XML response I wish to parse (this XML is sent as a response).  I am using RestAssurred (trying) and may be able to handle Namespaces using that library?

Comment: @Steerpike The XML snippet you posted it not valid XML. Updated answer.

Comment: the issue I have is, this is the snippet response I am served from the WebService, so I have to find a way of parsing so I can read values using xpath. I have used factory.setNamespaceAware(true); but I am unclear where to go from here

Comment: @Steerpike Are you absolutely positive that this is the response as received? Because `<tag0:SessionInfo CreateNewSession="true"
<AAASessionId="8IzujBAVOPVQrO1ySpNBoJ9x"/>` is wrong. You cannot parse this as XML.

Comment: Not positive - this is the console output from Intellij. Perhaps it is inserting those 'tag0' chars?

Comment: @Steerpike I'm not referring to the namespace. Either the SessionInfo element misses a closing tag or AAASessionId is an attribute, not an element. You have two successive '<' characters in your sample, without an '>' character in between.